# How to register a com interface exposed by a .net exe?

Tags: .net, delphi, com, activex, registration

I have a .net exe (sent to me, I didn't write it) that exposes a com interface.

I need to register it so I can see it in the list of available activex interfaces from delphi ide.

I need to do something like

```
registerinterface.exe file.exe
```

where of course `registerinterface.exe` is a placeholder for the real thing.

May you jelp me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `regasm.exe [pathtoexecutable]`. Regasm is in the .NET Framework installation directory. Note that the assembly will have to have a strong name, otherwise you will get an error.

Make sure to do this from an elevated command prompt if you are using Windows Vista / 7 if UAC is enabled.

Comment: Cool. I didn't know that .NET assemblies use REGASM even when what you want to do is consume COM objects that they export. I would have guessed you would use RegSvr32

Comment: Nope, `regasm` has some additional work to do. In the case of .NET, mscoree is actually what gets loaded first since it may need to load the CLR, then mscoree will load the .NET assembly. regsvr32 knows nothing about loading the execution engine.